# The max amount of tab groups (safari 15+)

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, tabs

We know safari already has a max limit of 500 tabs total, and with the new iOS 15 update, the number of tabs you currently have open is nicely displayed.

However, iOS 15 also introduced tab groups, which are synchronised across all devices. What is the amount of tab groups one account can have, max?

Comment: Warning to anyone who wants to test this, you can't mass-close tab groups.

Comment: Are you looking to solve a specific problem?

Comment: @Ezekiel depends if you’d consider me starting to use tab groups, en masse, for all of my in-progress reading and browsing as a “problem” :P (just for scale, the last time I had to restore my tabs on desktop because of a browser crash, they counted 2000+ total)

Comment: Tab groups do not keep the tabs active, so I'm sure the limit is higher than the existing tab limits would be.

Comment: I know, but that's why im curious to the limit of the amount of tab groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't create more than 20, when I create a 21st group it just disappears.